# Optional Value Error in Swift SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift-playground

I'm trying to run the following Swift/SpriteKit code in the Swift Playgrounds iPad app. But when I run it, I'm encountering the error `Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. What's causing that error and how can I fix it?
[image: This is the Error I am getting]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Comment: Any help on this?? this is a playground @rmaddy

Comment: Where is your GameScene?